# Clear code coverage information in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-coverage

I have configured IntelliJ to paint the background of any line that has been executed at runtime to green when running in Coverage mode.

At times, I would like to just make all the files in the project revert back to their old and typical background colors, i.e, to remove all the coverage information.

Is that possible? How?

Answer (score 248):

just close the coverage window with "x" button:

[image: closing window]

*update*: for the recent IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.x, you can hide coverage by clicking left-hand side coverage bar (the colored one, close to line numbers) and then `Hide coverage` link:

[image: closing window in IDEA 2018.2.x]

Comment: Note: the coverage window may be minimized... expand it first

Comment: That X is gone in 2018.2.3 and the "-" only hides the tool :( Now only the menu helps: Analyze - Hide coverage

Comment: @sjngm you can close tab inside Coverage tool with x

Answer (score 123):

[image]

You can just Right Click on your Project,

**Goto `Analyze -> Hide Coverage data`**

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + F6 : This is the shortcut

Comment: This option was moved : `Run -> Hide coverage`

Comment: Thanks! I had some trouble finding the setting!

Answer (score 96):

1. double **shift**;
2. input **hide**;
3. choose **Hide Coverage data**;
4. Over.

Comment: love it! and leant double **shift** 

Comment: No need step 4. : )

Comment: nailed it bro @

Answer (score 25):

After the newer update, it seems the "Hide Coverage" option is removed from the "Analyze" section. You can find the "Hide Coverage" option in the "Run" menu

Comment: For new version that's corect

Answer (score 17):

Go to View > Tool Windows > Coverage

Click on the small icon button Delete Coverage Database

[image: Clean coverage database]

Comment: I didn't have this icon, but opening and closing the view with "X" did it..

Comment: Hmm, may I ask about this screen shot?  What on earth is "Cloverage?"

Answer (score 5):

To view/close code coverage results
 => Run the desired class with coverage, select suite to show, and open class in the editor.
 => On the main menu, choose Analyze | Show/remove Code Coverage Data.

Answer (score 5):

**2022 Update:** now it's moved to `Run -> Show Coverage Data`

You can select which you want to show or hide.

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer from parse is still valid in 2023.3. Also, I use it with the reverse use-case to show former coverage data that intellij has hidden due to closing the coverage report

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35426254)